# Adding a property for a class that's only available in a later SDK

Tags: ios, sdk, backwards-compatibility

I want my application to run on iOS 3.0 and later and be a universal application.
My problem here:
What do I do, if my class needs a property of a class that's only introduced in a later SDK?

For example:
My class needs a property of a UIPopovercontroller, but that's only available in 3.2 and later.
Do i need to work  around by defining a property of NSObject instead and then casting around to UIPopoverController all the time?

Comment: same goes for implementing protocols

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/07/tips-tricks-for-conditional-ios3-ios32.html) on Cocoa with Love for more info about combining compile-time and run-time checks for class and method availability.  The preprocessor macros that Matt Gallagher developed and posted there may meet your needs.  You would have to adapt them a bit to nuance the distinction between 3.2 and 3.0, though.

All of that said, there aren't a lot of users on 3.x (as of January 2011, it was ~10%, now undoubtedly much less.)